# Translating an asp-classic SQL statement to recognizable terms

Tags: php, sql, asp-classic

I have this SQL statment in an ASP file that i to deal with, and i have never dealt with .asp before. I workly mainly with PHP some im more familiar with PHP's Select SQL statements.

I just need some assistance bringing it down to familiar terms:

```
SelectSQL   = "SELECT * FROM BusinessInfo WHERE ((CatID = " & intBusiness_Category & ") or (CatID2 = " & intBusiness_Category & ") or (CatID3 = " & intBusiness_Category & ")) and (intStatusCodeID = 1) and (intOnWeb = 1) Order By vcBusinessName"
```

Comment: Can you specify what part of the SQL you don't understand? The statement is selecting all rows and columns from the BusinessInfo table that have a value in the CatID, CatID2, or CatID3 columns that matches your variable (intBusiness_Category) and the intStatusCodeID and intOnWeb values are 1. It is also sorted by the values in the vcBusinessName column.

Comment: Jason that pretty much sorts it out for me

Comment: Jason, you should add that as the answer, so Brinard can accept as the answer.

Comment: For the record, SQL statement is the same in all languages. The difference is the language syntax, in this case string syntax and concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is selecting all rows and columns from the BusinessInfo table that have a value in the CatID, CatID2, or CatID3 columns that matches your variable (intBusiness_Category) and the intStatusCodeID and intOnWeb values are 1. It is also sorted by the values in the vcBusinessName column